# NullPointerException on start of Processing

Tags: java, android, windows, processing

Hello I am getting this error as soon as I start Processing. Processing was working fine few hours back. But now it is showing this error. Please help me[image: I am this error]
Thanks for any kind of help

Comment: show your contributionlistingjava class :140 lines ,get the nullpointer exception.

Comment: I have not written any code. As soon I start application it throws above error.

Comment: Do restart you device and Run you application again

Comment: Jigar , I tried rebooting , didn't work , any more suggestions ?

Comment: @Prasad Try redownloading processing?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just created another user account and moved my processing folder. Worked like a magic!